# Stub files using a WSDL file in j2me

Tags: web-services, java-me, wsdl2java, jsr172

Is it possible to generate stub files using a "WSDL" file?

I know how to generate stub files using wscompiler in j2me.

I have a wsdl file is it possible to create stub files using it?

I am using these stub files in my j2me application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several ways to generate stub files

1. Using **wscompile** you can generate stubs follow [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/JSR_172%3a_Accessing_a_.NET_Web_Service) link. The wscompile command line reference can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/z400007747424.html).
2. Using net beans creating **j2me web service client**.

Answer (score 1):

you can use J2ME's Wireless Toolkit for generating stubs.

```
steps : (1) Go to File Menu, Select Utilities
```

```
        (2) From the Utilities dialog box, Select "Stub Generator" option.
```

Comment: what if I need to consume a REST web service, how would i do that??