# How can a J2ME application insert data to a SQL Server 2008 R2 table?

Tags: sql-server, java-me

We want to allow data entry from a feature phone to a SQL Server table.
Where is there an article or example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java ME Application, you can not directly insertion of data entry to any remote server. To achieve requirement, you must use a mechanism called Web-Service. Your Java ME application will pass the data ( which is to be inserted into database on remote server ) to that Web-Service and the Web-Service will do the final job.

have a look at my answer [Java ME with Web-Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553899/996493).

Also look at this quetsion [How to use web service in J2ME application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897165/how-to-use-web-service-in-j2me-application)